# Fetching array data of php in angular js and not able to update data in php

Tags: php, angularjs

[image]I am new to angular js and i want to update the data of registration form in which  i am not able to update data and also how to print array values of php in script file of angular js.Please look forward above the code and give required solutions.

fetchdata.php:

```
<?php
    include_once('db.php');
    if(isset($_GET['action'])){
        if($_GET['action']=='add_data'){
          add_data();
        }
        else if($_GET['action']=='get_data'){
          get_data();
        }
        else if($_GET['action']=='delete_data'){
            delete_data();
        }
        else if($_GET['action']=='edit_data'){
            edit_data();
        }
        else if($_GET['action']=='update_data'){
            update_data();
        }
    }

    /*Insert Data*/
    function add_data(){    
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
        //print_r($data);
        $fname  = $data->fname;
        $lname  = $data->lname;
        $gender = $data->gender;
        $state  = $data->state;
        $query="INSERT INTO registration 
        (reg_fname, reg_lname, reg_gender, reg_state, reg_id)
         values ('".$fname."', '".$lname."', '".$gender."', '".$state."', NULL)";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        //echo $query;
        if ($result) {
        $arr = array('msg' => "Data Added Successfully!!!", 'error' => '');
        $jsn = json_encode($arr);
        //print_r($jsn);
        } 
        else{
            $arr = array('msg' => "", 'error' => 'Error in inserting records');
            $jsn = json_encode($arr);
            // print_r($jsn);
        }
    }

    /*View dATA*/
    function get_data(){
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM registration");
        $data = array();
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $data[] = array(
                "userid" =>   $row['reg_id'],
                "fname"  =>   $row['reg_fname'],
                "lname"  =>   $row['reg_lname'],
                "gender" =>   $row['reg_gender'],
                "state"  =>   $row['reg_state'],
             );
        }
           //print_r($row);
            print_r(json_encode($data));
            return json_encode($data);
    }

    /*dELETE dATA*/
    function delete_data(){
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")); 
        $index = $data->userid; 
        //print_r($data) ;
        $del = mysql_query("DELETE FROM registration WHERE reg_id = ".$index);
        if($del)
        return true;
        return false; 
    }

    /*Edit Data*/
    function edit_data(){
        $data  = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
        $index = $data->userid;         
        $qry   = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM registration WHERE reg_id = ".$index);
        $data = array();
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry)){
            $data[]=array(
            "userid" =>$row['reg_id'],
            "fname"  =>$row['reg_fname'],
            "lname"  =>$row['reg_lname'],
            "gender" =>$row['reg_gender'],
            "state"  =>$row['reg_state']
            );
        }
        print_r(json_encode($data));
        return json_encode($data);
    }

    /*update Data*/
    function update_data(){
        $data=json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
        $index  = $data->userid;
        $fname  = $data->fname;
        $lname  = $data->lname;
        $gender = $data->gender;
        $state  = $data->state;
        $query=mysql_query("Update registration SET
                reg_fname='".$fname."',reg_lname='".$lname."',
                reg_gender='".$gender."',reg_state='".$state."' 
                where reg_id=".$index);
        if ($query){
            $arr = array('msg' => "Product Updated Successfully!!!", 'error' => '');
            $jsn = json_encode($arr);
            // print_r($jsn);
        } else {
            $arr = array('msg' => "", 'error' => 'Error In Updating record');
            $jsn = json_encode($arr);
            // print_r($jsn);
        }
    }   
?>
```

controller.js:

```
var regform = angular.module('regform',[]);
regform.controller('formController',function($scope,$http){
    $scope.submit=true;
    $scope.reset=true;
    $scope.states = [
        {id:1,name:'Gujarat'},
        {id:2,name:'Haryana'},
        {id:3,name:'MP'},
    ];

    $scope.get_data = function(){
        $http.get('fetchdata.php?action=get_data').success(function(data){
            $scope.fields = data
            return $scope;
        });
    }

    $scope.Save = function(){
        $http.post('fetchdata.php?action=add_data',
            {
                'userid': $scope.userid,
                'fname' : $scope.fname,
                'lname' : $scope.lname,
                'gender': $scope.gender,
                'state' : $scope.selectedState,
            }
        )
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config){
            //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            //console.log("Data added successfully");
            $scope.get_data();
            //alert("Data added Successfully");
       });
    }

    $scope.delete_id = function(index){
       $http.post('fetchdata.php?action=delete_data',{
                'userid' : index
        })
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) { 
            $scope.get_data();
        })
    }

    /* Edit data*/
   $scope.edit_id = function(index){
        $scope.update=true;
        $scope.cancel=true;
        $scope.submit=false;
        $scope.reset=false;

        $http.post('fetchdata.php?action=edit_data', {
            'userid' : index
        }) 
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) { 
            //alert(data[0]["userid"]);
            //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            $scope.userid = data[0]["userid"];
            $scope.fname  = data[0]["fname"];
            $scope.lname  = data[0]["lname"];
            $scope.gender = data[0]["gender"];
            $scope.selectedState  = parseInt(data[0]["state"]); 
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config){

        });
    }

    $scope.Update = function(){
        $http.post('db.php?action=update_data', {
            'userid' : $scope.userid,
            'fname'  : $scope.fname, 
            'lname'  : $scope.lname, 
            'gender' : $scope.gender,
            'state'  : $scope.selectedState
        })
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                $scope.get_data();
                return $scope;
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config){

        });
    }
});
```

form.html

```
<html ng-app="regform">
    <head>
        <title>Registration Form</title>
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="controller.js">
            /*var regform = angular.module('regform',[]);
            regform.controller('formController',function($scope){
                $scope.states = [
                        {id:1,name:'Gujarat'},
                        {id:2,name:'Haryana'},
                        {id:3,name:'MP'},
                        ];

                $scope.formfields =[];
                $scope.Save = function(form){
                  $scope.formfields.push({fname: $scope.fname,lname: $scope.lname,gender: $scope.gender, state:$scope.state});  
                }


            });*/
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="formController">
        <form name="userForm">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    FirstName:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" ng-model="userid" name="userid">
                    <input ng-model="fname" type="text" required ng-minlength="4">
                    <span ng-show="userForm.fname.$error.required">
                         This is a required field
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    LastName:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input ng-model="lname" type="text">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Gender:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" ng-model="gender" value="male"   id="male" checked="checked">Male
                    <input type="radio" ng-model="gender" value="female" id="female">Female
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    State:
                </td>
                <td>
                <select id="stateform" ng-model="selectedState" ng-options="state.id as state.name for state in states">
                     <option value="">- - Make Selection - -</option>
                </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input name="check" id="check" type="checkbox" ng-model="accept" required />Accept
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                     <button ng-show="submit" ng-click="Save()">Save</button>
                     <button ng-show="update" ng-click="Update()">Update</button>
                </td>
                <td>
                     <button ng-show="reset" ng-click="Reset()" type="reset">Reset</button>
                     <button ng-show="cancel" ng-click="clear()">Cancel</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
            <br>
            <br>
            <table border="1">
                <thead>
                   <th>UserId</th>
                   <th>FirstName</th>
                   <th>LastName</th>
                   <th>Gender</th>
                   <th>State</th>
                   <th>Action</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody ng-init="get_data()">
                    <tr ng-repeat="field in fields">
                    <td>{{field.userid }}</td>
                    <td>{{field.fname | uppercase}}</td>
                    <td>{{field.lname}}</td>
                    <td>{{field.gender}}</td>
                    <td>{{field.state}}</td>
                    <td><a id="edit" href="" ng-click="edit_id(field.userid)">Edit</a>
                    |&nbsp;<a id="delete" href="" ng-click="delete_id(field.userid)" ng-confirm="Are you sure?">Delete</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hey cant see the code you mentioned but in general you can send your form data via post to a php file which is then inserten / updating the db

Comment: Not able to get your answer actually I am trying to access $arr varaiable in php it is inserting data but not able to get the value shown in it so how to fetch that value

Comment: Are you getting data inside success function of `` $scope.get_data`` function??

Comment: yes i am getting it the value in it but how to pop up with confirmation that form has been submitted?

Comment: your question is about how to fetch and display data right ??

Comment: Yes i want to fetch data but it is fetching the data on inserting but not able  to update the updated data and not fetching the updated data and ya also i am not able to know how to show popup for successfully inserting and updating data

Comment: Inside $scope.get_data function, once you assign data to $scope, return $scope.

Comment: Not able to get your answer

Comment: Take look at my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82912/discussion-between-sameer-k-and-prachi-varaiya).

Comment: This question is incoherent and I have no idea why 7 people upvoted it. I can't tell what you're asking, but I'm pretty sure you didn't need to dump 300 lines of badly-formatted code on us in order to ask it. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have look at below changes where i tried to address your issues.

1) Using below HTML code to list state value

`<select id="stateform" ng-model="selectedState" ng-options="state.id as state.name for state in states">
 </select>`

Here i am using ng-model `selectedState` which will be set to 0 (make a selection) by default using `$scope.selectedState = 0;` in angularJS function.

2) To show data on load and after insert/update , return $scope like below

```
 $scope.get_data = function(){
    $http.get('update-data.php?action=get_data').success(function(data){

        $scope.fields = data;
        return $scope;
    });
}
```

3) Wherever you are using `$scope.state.name` , use `$scope.selectedState` as i change ng-model.

Below is complete AngularJS code

```
var regform = angular.module('regform',[]);
regform.controller('formController',function($scope,$http){
$scope.submit=true;
$scope.reset=true;
$scope.selectedState = 0;
$scope.states = [
        {id:0,name:'Make selection'},
        {id:1,name:'Gujarat'},
        {id:2,name:'Haryana'},
        {id:3,name:'MP'},
        ];

$scope.get_data = function(){
    $http.get('update-data.php?action=get_data').success(function(data){

        $scope.fields = data;
        return $scope;
    });
}

$scope.Save = function(){
    $http.post('update-data.php?action=add_data',
        {
            'userid': $scope.userid,
            'fname' : $scope.fname,
            'lname' : $scope.lname,
            'gender': $scope.gender,
            'state' : $scope.selectedState,
        }
    )
    .success(function (){
        $scope.get_data();
        alert('Data updated!!!');
     });
}

$scope.delete_id = function(index){
    $http.post('update-data.php?action=delete_data',{
            'userid' : index
        }
        )
    .success(function () { 
        $scope.get_data();
    })
}
/* Edit data*/
$scope.edit_id = function(index){
    $scope.update=true;
    $scope.cancel=true;
    $scope.submit=false;
    $scope.reset=false;

    $http.post('update-data.php?action=edit_data', {
        'userid' : index
    }) 
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) { 
        //console.log(data);
        //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        $scope.userid = data[0]["userid"];
        $scope.fname  = data[0]["fname"];
        $scope.lname  = data[0]["lname"];
        $scope.gender = data[0]["gender"];
        $scope.selectedState  = parseInt(data[0]["state"]); 
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config){

    });
}
$scope.Update = function(){
    $http.post('update-data.php?action=update_data', 
        {
            'userid' : $scope.userid,
            'fname'  : $scope.fname, 
            'lname'  : $scope.lname, 
            'gender' : $scope.gender,
            'state'  : $scope.selectedState
        }
    )
    .success(function () {
            $scope.get_data();
            alert('Data updated!!!');
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config){

    });
}
});
```

Now `reg_state` stores numeric value representing state and state name and use mysqli or PDO instead mysql as it is depricated.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Still not able to get updated data On success function of update empty string is returning to data. Hence no changes occurrs in updating data.

Comment: Thx For the selected state option it is nice but still it is not able to update the data on clicking the update buttton it is not able to replace the data on the view of that data

Comment: Thank you for sharing the code with add, edit, select and delete functionality with angularJS. Sure it will help many like me. And the update function is just working fine for me.  I double checked. Are you getting error?? and also clear browser cache and try again.

Comment: yup i am getting blank string just remove comment from json.stringify(data) i am getting empty string

Comment: Ok i think no need to check for return data from update function as ``$scope.get_data();`` inside success of update function will retrieve the updated data. Even we can get rid of arguments for success method for save, delete and update function. Will edit my answer. And just want to know whether whether you are returning $scope inside ``$scope.get_data()`` function??

Comment: yes i have return the $scope but still not getting the value

Comment: can you update your question with latest code that you have (HTML, JS and php), so that i will use them in my local to test.

Comment: yup i have updated and also send a image of one i am getting error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82924/discussion-between-prachi-varaiya-and-sameer-k).